# Linq to Sql - DateTime Format - YYYY-MMM (2009-Mar)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to write a Linq to Sql query that does a count and groups by a Username and DateTime. I want the DateTime to be formatted like following "YYYY-MMM" (i.e. 2009-Mar).

I thought this would work but Linq to Sql can't parse the ToString "format" argument.

```
            dc.MyTable
              .GroupBy(r => new
              {
                  Name = r.UserName,
                  YearMonth = r.SomeDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM")
              })
              .Select(r => new
              {
                  Name = r.UserName,
                  YearMonth = r.YearMonth,
                  Count = r.Count()
              })
              .OrderBy(r => r.YearMonth)
              .ThenBy(r => r.Name);
```

Does anyone have any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way - if you want, you can actually write this with the query syntax rather than the fluent/extension approach. But if you're happy with the current code, leave it "as is"...

Comment: I actually prefer the extension/lambda syntax over the query syntax.  Just a personal preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder if you shouldn't do that the "long" way...

```
          dc.MyTable
          .GroupBy(r => new
          {
              Name = r.UserName,
              Year = r.SomeDateTime.Year,
              Month = r.SomeDateTime.Month
          })
          .Select(r => new
          {
              Name = r.UserName,
              Year = r.Year,
              Month = r.Month,
              Count = r.Count()
          })
          .OrderBy(r => r.Year)
          .ThenBy(r => r.Month)
          .ThenBy(r => r.Name);
```

If you need the format as a string, do that later at the UI. Either by reconstructing a `DateTime` etc, or using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(...)`.

Comment: Not the answer I "wanted" but I think probably the most correct.  Thanks for the tip on using DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(...).

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid turning anything into a string at the database. Group by `r.SomeDateTime.Year` and `r.SomeDateTime.Month`, ordering by year then month then name, select the year and the month separately (along with the count), and then if you need to do the projection to a string format back in the client code.

By the way, I suspect your second `OrderBy` should be a `ThenBy` - currently the `Name` is actually the *most* important thing you're ordering by.

Comment: Well, you're +71 on me today - I suspect you'll survive ;-p