# What is the correct way to get a sortable string from a DateTime in a LINQ entity?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
// EmployeeService:
[WebMethod]
public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    return
        (
            from p in db.Persons
            where p.Type == 'E'
            select new Employee
            {
                Name = p.FullName,
                //HireDate = p.CreationDate.ToString(), 
                // works, but not in the format I need

                //HireDate = p.CreationDate.ToString("s"), 
                // throws a NotSupportedException

                //HireDate = Wrapper(p.CreationDate), 
                // works, but makes me worry about performance 
                // and feel dead inside
            }
        ).ToList<Employee>();
}

private String Wrapper(DateTime date)
{
    return date.ToString("s");
}

// Elsewhere:
public class Employee
{
    public String Name;
    public String HireDate;
}
```

I'm using a JavaScript framework that needs dates in ISO 8601 style format, which is exactly what calling `.ToString("s")` on a `DateTime` object will return.

**Is there a cleaner/more efficient way to do this in LINQ to SQL?**

Comment: My $0.02: There's no rule which says you have to display and sort on the same thing. This is one of those times when you shouldn't. Return a DateTime. JavaScriptSerializer handles these in a proprietary format. Deserialize in JS to JS Dates. Your sort will work.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: Agreed, although sorting isn't really my issue; it's more a matter of ExtJS handling (esp. parsing) ISO 8601 much more cleanly than .NET's proprietary format.  `.ToString("s")` on Get and a `TryParse()` on Save result in fewer headaches (in my particular case).

Comment: What we do (in jQuery, but should be portable to Ext) is to have a deserialization filter on the returned JSON which looks for the MS format and replaces it with a `Date` during deserialization.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: You might consider posting that deserialization filter somewhere; I'd like to see it.

Comment: This will give you the general idea: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/problems-with-jquery-1-4-ajax-and-dates.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `Wrapper` trick is as good as you can get in this situation. Sorry.

**Update:** Seems this has been asked again here: [Linq to Sql - DateTime Format - YYYY-MMM (2009-Mar)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/632606/50079). The answer was pretty much "sorry" there too; considering who participated in that question, I 'm now really sure that you can't do better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when using `IQueryable`, the provider tries to translate all of the LINQ expressions into something it can send down to the database. It has no way of knowing what to do with `ToString("s")`, so the `NotSupported` exception is thrown.

If you were to add `.AsEnumerable()` before the `Select` call, then it should work. The difference is that the `Person` object will be brought into memory completely, then the projection (the Select) method will be ran and all of that is done as a .NET compiled method, not as SQL. So essentially anything after `AsEnumerable()` will be done in memory and not in the database, so it's generally not recommended to do until you've trimmed down the number of rows as much as possible (i.e. after all `Where` and `OrderBy`s).